# Compiling Sass with Scout doesn't apply correct alpha value when using rgba(r,g,b,a)

Tags: sass

When I want to add a background color to one of the containers, using rgba(r,g,b,a) with an alpha transparency of "0.5" or what ever, compass turns it into "0" at the end.

Sass:

```
.main-content{
   background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

Output:

```
.main-content{
   background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
```

Comment: Seems related: https://github.com/mhs/scout-app/issues/22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug, and it will be fixed soon, meanwhile try using this workaround:

```
background: rgba(255,255,255,1/2);
```

Comment: thank you, you were right. Using 1/2 worked like a charm. I did a lot of research on google about compass issues regarding compiling rgba function, but I found nothing!

Where did you find out?

Comment: Take a look at a comment from a user named **donteat** here in this [webpage](https://github.com/mhs/scout-app/issues/22)

Answer (score -1):

Does this help it at all? Adding `!important` will overrule any other style from other stylesheets.

```
//SCSS in my _main-content.scss
.main-content{
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5) !important;
}
```